# Desactivar rotación de pantalla en android studio

Tags: android, studio, actualizacion, sensor

Necesito que mi app se vea solo en posición vertical... las soluciones que encuentro no aplican a 2020, ya que modificaron las condiciones de android studio.

Comment: Hola satavisky, por favor añade más información a tu pregunta: ¿qué soluciones probaste y no funcionan? ¿qué versión de Android Studio estás usando? ¿Qué lenguaje de programación estás utilizando para desarrollar tu app? Lee [ask] y completa el [tour] y edita tu pregunta con las recomendaciones que encontrarás ahí.

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres cambiar la rotacion del activity mediante código java , en cada activity debes colocar despues del **setContentView** o cuando tu quieras activar la rotacion, una de estas lineas

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)//vertical
   


 setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)//horizontal



setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LOCKED)//bloquear rotacion
```

si utilizas el ide android studio, veras que al escribir  **setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.**  cuando escribas el punto veras que te apacere todo la lista de opciones o constantes que puedes utilizar para detectar las rotaciones de la pantalla o activity, por ejemplo cuando se activa un sensor...

si utilizas codigo kolin debes utilizar

```
 requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE
```

si quieres ejecutar un determinado codigo cuando la pantalla este en una posicion determinada en kotlin lo puedes hacer de esta forma.... (desconozco como es en java, pero imagino que sera muy parecido)

```
objectoContext.resources.configuration.orientation== Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT


objectoContext.resources.configuration.orientation== Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE
```

por ejemplo

```
if(this.resources.configuration.orientation== Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT ){

    codigo que se ejecuta cuando la pantalla este en posicion horizontal
}
```

si utilizas el ide android studio, veras que al escribir  **Configuration.**  cuando escribas el punto veras que te apacere todo el lista de opciones o constantes que puedes utilizar para detectar las rotaciones de la pantalla o activity, por ejemplo cuando se activa un sensor...

el equivalente de estas ultimas lineas de código en Java seria asi

```
if(this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation== Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT ){
   
      código que se ejecuta cuando la pantalla este en posicion horizontal
            
}
```

Comment: usé esta línea:                                 setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)                      pero me tira error. Me obligó a poner esta otra linea antes:          @SuppressLint("SourceLockedOrientationActivity")      y funciona. Muchas gracias!

Comment: si utilizas kotlin prueba con requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE

Answer (score 0):

Tienes dos opciones, esto es una especie de advertencia para informar a los desarrolladores que para dispositivos de pantallas grandes no es bueno restringir la orientacion. Sin embargo, si su aplicacion solo admite un solo modo puedes desactivar esta advertencia.

Para MAC: Android Studio -> Preferencias
Para Windows: File o Archivos -> Preferecias

Luego vamos a Editor->Inspection->Android->Lint->Correctnes->Chrome OS

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La otra opcion es seguir los siguientes pasos:

Caso 1: Para bloquear la orientacion

Paso 1: Agregar lo siguiente en el tag de Application en el AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
       android:name=".activity.MyApplication"
       tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity">
```

Paso 2: Si desea bloquear la orientacion de alguna pantalla solo hay que agregar la siguiente linea en los Tag Activity

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait" or "landscape"
```

Caso 2: Supongamos que desea que permitirla orientacion en una actividad en particular y tiene un diseño especifico en landscape

Paso 1: Elimine el valor de la orientacion en configchange y elimine la orientacion de la pantalla si existe el tag Activity, y por sugerencia personal utilice LifecycleObserver para no perder valores al cambiar la orientacion

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
android:screenOrientation="portrait" or "landscape"
```

Espero que te haya sido de ayuda.